# docker-compose creating multiple set of services

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mattermost

I'm trying to create 3 [mattermost](https://github.com/mattermost/mattermost-docker) services on 1 AWS EC2 machine.

Let me explain further with more texts:

When I run `docker-compose up -d`, I get a service whose structure is like this:

[image]

How can I modify the docker related scripts so that I can create 3 sets of service?

[image]

I've tried `docker-compose up --scale app=3 --scale web=3 --scale db=3`. But I can't find any way to specify different port for each of the `App` container.

The only solution I've found is:

1. Create 3 copies of `mattermost-docker` folder.
2. Change the `App` port and database connection information.
3. Run `docker-compose up -d` 3 times in `mattermost-docker1`, `mattermost-docker2`, and `mattermost-docker3` separately.

But this solution creates a lot of duplicated files. I don't like it.

Anyone knows how to create 3 sets of mattermost services?

Comment: I think you should 3 different files as docker-compose itself is a binary which works under the hood with Docker engine to create 3 different set of mattermost services. Also it is better for the sake of maintainability.

Comment: See if this is of any help https://tarunlalwani.com/post/docker-compose-scale-with-dynamic-configuration-part-1/ ?

Comment: Share content of docker compose file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a port range in docker compose:

For example, for 10 container scalling:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    ...
    ports:
      - "80-90:443"

  app:
    ...
    ports:
      - "8000-8010"
```

Note that you don't need to change port inside container (443, 444, 445). You can use the same, and furthermore that's recommended, because although you use different containers in a port range, is easier if they use the same nginx configuration.

Comment: But how can I create 3 different names for the 3 databases?

Comment: Why do you need that? You can create the same database name. Each container is independent from others.

Answer (score 0):

This starts sets of services using 3 separate databases (nginx and mongo used as example).

```
  version: '3'

  services:

    web1:
      container_name: web1
      image: nginx:latest
      ports:
        - 8080:8080

    app1:
      container_name: app1
      image: nginx:latest
      ports:
        - "8081:8081"
    db1:
      container_name: db1
      image: mongo
      ports:
        - 27017

    web2:
      container_name: web2
      image: nginx:latest
      ports:
        - 8082:8082

    app2:
      container_name: app2
      image: nginx:latest
      ports:
        - "8083:8083"
    db2:
      container_name: db2
      image: mongo
      ports:
        - 27018

    web3:
      container_name: web3
      image: nginx:latest
      ports:
        - 8084:8084
    app3:
      container_name: app3
      image: nginx:latest
      ports:
        - "8085:8085"
    db3:
      container_name: db3
      image: mongo
      ports:
        - 27019
```

**Local Test:**

```
NAMES                STATUS                PORTS                                   IMAGE
db2                  Up About a minute     27017/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32803->27018/tcp     mongo
web1                 Up About a minute     80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32802->8080/tcp         nginx:latest
db1                  Up About a minute     0.0.0.0:32801->27017/tcp                mongo
app1                 Up About a minute     80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32800->8081/tcp         nginx:latest
app3                 Up About a minute     80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32798->8085/tcp         nginx:latest
db3                  Up About a minute     27017/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32799->27019/tcp     mongo
app2                 Up About a minute     80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32797->8083/tcp         nginx:latest
web3                 Up About a minute     80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32796->8084/tcp         nginx:latest
web2                 Up About a minute     80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32795->8082/tcp         nginx:latest
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. But it looks like that mattermost doesn't support changing `app` port by configuring `docker-compose.yml`. Maybe I have to dive deeper to modify the files under `app` folder.

Comment: I'll take closer look at it